# Deploying Mern stack app with Multer for file uploads

Tags: deployment, multer

I recently finished an e-commerce MERN stack app to ad to my portfolio. Now I want to deploy It but have no idea where to start. I use multer middleware for file storage and images are being stored in an uploads folder in my project diroctory, I followed a youtube video tutorial to learn how to do this. But now I want to deploy my app so I can add to my portfolio but I am very lost. If anyone has any suggestions on where I should look to move forward It would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

I researched on youtube but couldnt find anything similar to what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Render.com is a free deployment site. I deployed a MERN app on render and it’s a streamlined process. I have my front end and back end on there. You should look up a YouTube tutorial but basically you add a web service for backend and then a static web page for front end. Make sure to have the connection strings updated, build configured, and test before deployment.